# LiquidHaskell: Functor Law

Tags: liquid-haskell

I am encoding (as an assumption) the functor identity law like so:

```hs
...
import qualified Prelude ()
...


{-@ class Functor f where
      fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b) @-}
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)


-- identity function
{-@ id :: forall a . x : a -> {y : a | x = y} @-}
id :: forall a . a -> a
id x = x

-- functor law: mapping with identity is identity
{-@ assume
    fmap_id :: forall f a . Functor f => x : f a ->
      {fmap id x = id x} @-}
fmap_id :: Functor f => f a -> ()
fmap_id _ = ()
```

I can't see anything wrong with this formulation, yet I get this error from LH:

```
src/Category/Functor/LH.hs:45:16: error:
    • Illegal type specification for `Category.Functor.LH.fmap_id`
    Category.Functor.LH.fmap_id :: forall f a .
                                   (Functor<[]> f) =>
                                   x:f a -> {VV : () | Category.Functor.LH.fmap Category.Functor.LH.id x == Category.Functor.LH.id x}
    Sort Error in Refinement: {VV : Tuple | Category.Functor.LH.fmap Category.Functor.LH.id x == Category.Functor.LH.id x}
    Unbound symbol Category.Functor.LH.fmap --- perhaps you meant: Category.Functor.LH.C:Functor ?
    •
   |
45 |     fmap_id :: forall f a . Functor f => x : f a ->
   |
```

What am I doing wrong? My goal is to formulate this point-free with extensionality, but at least this point-wise formulation should work first.

Configuration:

- GHC version: 8.10.1
- Cabal version: 3.2.0.0
- Liquid Haskell version: 0.8.10.2

Answer (score 2):

Support for typeclasses is not yet supported in the official release of Liquid Haskell (although it is [almost ready to merge](https://github.com/ucsd-progsys/liquidhaskell/pull/1778)). For now, you can use [this fork](https://github.com/plum-umd/oopsla2020-artifact) which implements typeclass support. After recursively cloning the repository, you can install the forked version with:

```
pushd liquid-benchmark/liquidhaskell
stack install
popd
```

We define `Functor` and its laws (in the `VFunctor` subclass) in `liquid-base/liquid-base/src/Data/Functor/Classes.hs` as follows. Notice that you can specify refinements on the typeclass methods directly.

```
class Functor f where
  {-@ fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b @-}
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  (<$) :: a -> f b -> f a

class Functor m => VFunctor m where
  {-@ lawFunctorId :: forall a . x:m a -> {fmap id x == id x} @-}
    lawFunctorId :: m a -> ()

  {-@ lawFunctorComposition :: forall a b c . f:(b -> c) -> g:(a -> b) -> x:m a -> { fmap (compose f g) x == compose (fmap f) (fmap g) x } @-}
  lawFunctorComposition :: forall a b c. (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> m a -> ()
```

You can run the forked version of Liquid Haskell on the typeclass definitions with:

```
liquid --typeclass -i liquid-base/liquid-base/src/ liquid-base/liquid-base/src/Data/Functor/Classes.hs
```

We create a verified `Maybe` instance in `liquid-base/liquid-base/src/Data/Maybe/Functor.hs` with:

```
instance Functor Maybe where
  fmap _ Nothing = Nothing
  fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
  _ <$ Nothing = Nothing
  x <$ (Just _) = Just x

instance VFunctor Maybe where
  lawFunctorId Nothing = ()
  lawFunctorId (Just _) = ()
  lawFunctorComposition f g Nothing = ()
  lawFunctorComposition f g (Just x) = ()
```

You can run Liquid Haskell on the `Maybe` instance to verify that it satisfies the required laws:

```
liquid --typeclass -i liquid-base/liquid-base/src/ liquid-base/liquid-base/src/Data/Maybe/Functor.hs
```